# What is a single pole 30 amp breaker used for

Tags: electrical

Is ok to us a 30 amp breaker single pole according to NEC

Comment: A single pole 30A breaker is used for 120V 30A circuits. But what are you going to use it for?

Comment: do you have 120 volt load that needs 16 to 24 amps?

Comment: @Skaperen, a load of 16-20A does NOT automatically require the use of a 30A circuit. Again, it depends on what it is being used for.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it is OK to use. What you use it for is the question.

You CANNOT user it for general purpose 15 & 20 amp receptacles.

Basically, about the only things you can use one for in a residence would be for a TT130 120V/30A travel trailer receptacle circuit.

Problem is, we see them installed quite often for 20A circuits that are overloaded and tripping. People with no clue about code or safety replace 20A breakers with them.

Comment: Or a 2500kva uninterruptible power supply that runs off 120VAC

Comment: Why can you not use a 30Amp breaker for 15 & 20 amp receptacles?

Comment: @nueverest, it is expressly against code (NEC in the US).

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Why?

Comment: @nueverest, you'll have to ask the code making panels that one. Unless it's a really stupid code I tend to not question them. Some are common sense. The NEC does not explain the reasoning behind its codes.

Comment: A motor load would be a place a single pole 30 amp breaker is allowed. Code allows a larger breaker to prevent tripping on startup.+ but I agree with @speedy petey.

Answer (score 1):

"Why can you not use a 30Amp breaker for 15 & 20 amp receptacles?"

Two appliances drawing more than 15 or 20 amps will be allowed to run without tripping the breaker, which can overheat/melt the outlet. Plus, standard wiring is 12 or 14 gauge so not only will the outlet be overloaded, but the wiring will too, even if you split the appliances between multiple outlets. All wiring and receptacles downstream of an over current protective device must be rated for the amperage of the over current protective device.

Comment: No it won't.  Why should it?

Comment: I should have said CAN, not will. Two appliances drawing more than 15 or 20 amps  will be allowed to run without tripping the breaker, which can overheat/melt the outlet.  Plus, standard wiring is 12 or 14 gauge so not only will the outlet be overloaded, but the wiring will too, even if you split the appliances between multiple outlets.  All wiring and receptacles downstream of an over current protective device must be rated for the amperage of the over current protective device.

Comment: I suggest that you edit that into your answer rather than leave it as a comment.

Comment: Done - but this may be the only time I contribute. I think anyone asking electrical questions should consult a more rigorous source, especially those people not understanding ampacity.